# How to export a signed apk using NBandroid for Netbeans 8?

Tags: android, netbeans, export

I'm trying to export a signed apk using Netbeans 8.0.2.

So far, I have a debug version of the apk (signed with a debug key) on one hand, and a keystore file on the other.

According to the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html), I should first generate an unsigned release version before being able to use the CLI.

Looking for a straight-forward solution, I installed the NBandroid plugin, as I understood that an "export wizard" was supposed to be added to the [project contextual menu](http://www.nbandroid.org/2011/05/building-signed-packages.html). However, although this plugin looks properly installed ("NBAndroid Graddle Support"), I can't find this option in the context menu.

What would be my best (and easiest) options to generate this signed apk?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up with Netbeans and exported from Eclipse.